# Trying to work with API JSON output in Python

Tags: python, json

I am a newbie to the world of Python and JSON though I've managed to work my way through most problems. The latest though is stumping me. I am trying to work with the API at localbitcoins.com and the JSON file is here [LBC_JSON](https://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/alipay/.json)--it's a public file.

The output is quite large. I have tried working with it pandas using this code:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from pandas.io.json import read_json

pandas_json = read_json('https://localbitcoins.com/buy-bitcoins-online/alipay/.json')

print(len(pandas_json))
print(type(pandas_json))
print(pandas_json)
```

But the completed data is not outputted, and then, not completely.

I have tried using the requests library and generating a response.json() on the response. Even though this brings in the complete data I cannot find a way to access the data that I need. I've tried iteration through the data with no luck. All I need is the first price in the API.

I have managed to get this info by using BeautifulSoup and CSS tags but I don't feel this is the correct way to access this info since an API is provided.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to iterate over `ad_list`, for example:

```
for ad in pandas_json['data']['ad_list']:
    print(ad['data']['profile']['username'], ad['data']['temp_price'])
```